# Entanglement in VQE ansatz in Qiskit

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, qiskit

The Qiskit documentation on VQE [describes](https://qiskit.org/documentation/aqua/variational_forms.html#ry) two of the ansatz as "rotations with entanglements". The rotation gates are more or less clear, but the documentation doesn't mention what gate is used for entanglement. I suspect they use something like $\exp(-i \alpha Z_1 Z_2)$, but what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the entangler gates are controlled-PHASE gates, at least that is mentioned in the Qiskit [tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/aqua/chemistry/dissociation_profile_of_molecule.ipynb):

$$
c\text{PHASE} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & i \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, in hardware, one also uses the [drift Hamiltonian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.05018.pdf) $U_{\text{ENT}}=\exp(-iH_0 \tau)$, which naturally entangles all qubits.